# Onesignal API in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight App

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, onesignal

I made a little app started with Databound App template. Didn't have an idea that it made use of Silverlight and at same time that this was making this framework uncompatible. I have to install Onesignal API to it for push notifications. So, I followed the [documentation procedure](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/windows-phone-81-sdk-install).

It failed at 1.4 with this error when pressing OK:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio
A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project
```

So I tried to do the same thing, in case I did something wrong, on the Blank App template which doesn't feature Silverlight and it worked.

How can either install the API in my Silverlight project or "convert" (or migrate) it to non-Silverlight?

Comment: It looks like the library is for the win phone 8,1 (rt based) not the wp8.1 silverlight project

Comment: So what should I do? Recreate the project or there is a way to migrate the project? Also there is a good template for starting with a master-viewdetail app like Databound template?